# Handling null results with the LINQ Average() method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) and am trying to create some data points from a table to graph. The three fields of importance in this table are the id, the time and the value. I am writing a query to get the average value over a set time for a chosen id. The LINQ I have written follows:

```
var value = (from t in _table
             where t.Id == id
                 && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
                 && t.Time <= intervalEndTime
             select t.Value).Average();
```

However this crashes at runtime with:

> "The null value cannot be assigned to
>   a member with type System.Decimal
>   which is a non-nullable value type.."

At certain intervals there is no data so the SQL LINQ generates returns null, which I would liked to be COALESCED to 0 but instead crashes the application. Is there a way to write this LINQ query to be able to handle this properly?

The table definition to make things clearer:

```
[Serializable]
[Table(Name = "ExampleTable")]
public class ExampleTable
{
    [Column(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Time")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Value")]
    public int Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you want

```
var value = (from t in _table
             where t.Id == id
                && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
                && t.Time <= intervalEndTime
             select (int?)t.Value).Average()
```

This way, you get a `double?` back, whereas without the `(int?)` cast you need to get a `double` back, which cannot be `null`.

This is because of the signatures

```
double Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable<int> source)
double? Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable<int?> source)
```

Now, to get an average of 0 instead of null, you need to place the coalescing operator at the end

```
var value = (from t in _table
             where t.Id == id
                && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
                && t.Time <= intervalEndTime
             select (int?)t.Value).Average() ?? 0.0;
```

---

IMHO this is a pretty awful design of the `Enumerable`/`Queryable` class; why can't `Average(IEnumerable<int>)` return `double?`, why only for `Average(IEnumerable<int?>)`?

Comment: just to assist others in this issue: if the query *doesn't return any rows*, nothing will really help. you just have to avoid running the query altogether. at least that was my experience.

Comment: @horace: That's simply not true. Average, Min, Max, Sum all work when the query matches no rows *as long as the aggregate result is nullable*. As you can see in the query above, you'll need a cast to enforce nullability when the expression to aggregate is not of a nullable type. (In the rare case it still doesn't work, you're probably dealing with a flaky LINQ provider. That's not LINQ's fault, and no provider I know of is that messed up.)

Answer (score 17):

Okay, how about this:

```
var value = (from t in _table
             where t.Id == id
                 && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
                 && t.Time <= intervalEndTime
             select t.Value).DefaultIfEmpty().Average()
```

I believe that's *logically* what you want - changing {} to {0}, so making all averages achievable. I don't know if it'll do what you want in terms of SQL though.

Comment: Thanks but still no joy.  Throws a "Could not format node 'OptionalValue' for execution as SQL."

Comment: +1 DefaultIfEmpty() takes away the problem of what to do if the where part of the linq reduces the set to no rows

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Total Rework

Try casting the value to nullable first

```
var value = (from t in _table
         where t.Id == id
             && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
             && t.Time <= intervalEndTime
         select ((int?)t.Value) ?? 0).Average()
```

Comment: select t.Value ?? 0 doesn't compile as t.Value is a non-nullable int.

Comment: Yes, the complier tells me the left operand will never be null as Value is not nullable

Comment: Are you sure you have the brackets etc. correct? The cast to nullable is legit so Value should have already been evaluated...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It will simply skip all the null items returned by the query.

```
var value = (from t in _table
             where t != null
             where t.Id == id
                 && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
                 && t.Time <= intervalEndTime
             select t.Value).Average();
```

If you want to explicitly treat the null items as zero, then a simple use of the *conditional operator* should do the job:

```
var value = (from t in _table
             where t == null ||
                 (t.Id == id
                 && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
                 && t.Time <= intervalEndTime)
             select t == null ? 0 : t.Value).Average();
```

Comment: How can `t` be null, and be between `intervalStartTime` and `intervalEndTime`? I think his problem is that there are no records between certain start and end times, not that there are nulls in the table.

Comment: Oh, t.Value vs. t.Time - I see.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still throws the same exception.

Comment: @Dominic: The first example should not through any excepts. I've now updated the second example to fix it (indeed, it was incomplete).

Comment: Sorry again.  Tried them both.  They still throw "The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.." Exception

Comment: Where is this error occuring? Could you paste the stack trace perhaps, please?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a temp for the initial query?

E.g:

```
var temp = (from t in _table
            where t.Id == id
                && t.Time >= intervalStartTime
                && t.Time <= intervalEndTime
            select t.Value) ??  new List<int>() {0};
var value = temp.Average();
```

Not sure if this helps.